# How to get the identity of the connected user via the Bitbucket REST API?

Tags: rest, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

in the Stash REST API, after having retrieved an OAuth token, I'd like to get the identity of the connected user (username, email, ...). But I can't find a resource in the doc that let me do it without knowing the username at least.

Is there a way to achieve this without knowing the username?

In JIRA, there seems to be a resource to do this:

```
"/rest/gadget/1.0/currentUser"
```

but I couldn't find something similar in Stash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can retrieve the username of the currently authenticated user by doing a GET to the following resource (relative to the base URL of your Stash server):

```
/plugins/servlet/applinks/whoami
```

You can then use this username to retrieve the rest of the user's profile data from the REST API.